# threejs raycaster cannot intersect in stereoscopic mode

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make use of Raycaster in a ThreeJS scene to create a sort of VR interaction.
Everything works fine in normal mode, but not when I enable stereo effect.

I am using the following snippet of code.

```
// "camera" is a ThreeJS camera, "objectContainer" contains objects (Object3D) that I want to interact with
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
origin = new THREE.Vector2();
origin.x = 0; origin.y = 0;

raycaster.setFromCamera(origin, camera);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objectContainer.children, true);

if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].object.visible === true) {
    // trigger some function myFunc()
}
```

So basically when I try the above snippet of code in normal mode, **myFunc** gets triggered whenever I am *looking at* any of the concerned 3d objects.
However as soon as I switch to stereo mode, it stops working; i.e., **myFunc** never gets triggered.

I tried updating the value of **origin.x** to -0.5. I did that because in VR mode, the screen gets split into two halves. However that didn't work either.

What should I do to make the raycaster intersect the 3D objects in VR mode (when stereo effect is turned on)?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide a jsfiddle with the code?

Basically, if you are using stereo in your app, it means you are using 2 cameras, therefore you need to check your intersects on both cameras views, this could become an expensive process.

```
var cameras = 
    { 'camera1': new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000),
    'camera2': new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
    };

for (var cam in cameras) {
    raycaster.setFromCamera(origin, cameras[cam]);
    //continue your logic
}
```

You could use a vector object that simulates the camera intersection to avoid checking twice, but this depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found that in stereo mode, ThreeJS does utilize 2 separate cameras. I shall try updating the StereoEffect.js library file according to my needs. If it works, I shall post back here.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, I eventually found the reason. Actually in StereoEffect THREE.js *displays* the meshes on the two eyes, but in reality is actually adds only one mesh to the scene, exactly in the middle of the line left-eye-mesh <-> right-eye-mesh, hidden to the viewer.

So when you use the raycaster, you need to use it on the **real** mesh on the middle, not the illusion displayed on each eye !

I detailled here how to do it 
[Three.js StereoEffect displays meshes across 2 eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540403/three-js-stereoeffect-displays-meshes-across-2-eyes)

Hopes it solves your problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [StereoEffect.js](https://github.com/anhr/three.js/blob/5d0101b8273af239e6080de53e93d615a1885b65/examples/js/effects/StereoEffect.js) file in your project for resolving problem. See [example](https://raw.githack.com/anhr/three.js/raycaster_stereo/examples/webgl_raycaster_stereo.html) of using. See my [Raycaster stereo pull request](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/16221) also.